# Not able to send html body using mailx along with attachement

Tags: linux, sendmail, mailx, uuencode

I tried command : mailx -s "subject" "xzy@ygmail.com" < abc.html
Using this command html content is displayed as text which is not desirable.

above thing happened using :

While using command :  mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "my subject" "xzy@ygmail.com" < abc.html ,
exception is displayed " Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory".

Also tried using : echo "abc.html" | mail -a ""Content-type: text/html;" -s "subject" "xzy@ygmail.com"  --but didn't work.

Please note I cannot use sendmail command as uuencode is not properly installed hence attachment are not sent with mail properly though html content is properly displayed.

So please advice how to effectively use "mailx" command to send html content with attachments.